# Passing values to multiple views

Tags: php, yii2

I've this code for the controller (I'm using the basic template for testing purposes:

```
use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $param = $this->somefunction();
        return $this->render('index', [
             "param" => $param
        ]);
    }

    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }

    public function actionContact()
    {
         $param = $this->somefunction();
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');

            return $this->refresh();
        } else {
            return $this->render('contact', [
                'model' => $model,
                 "param" => $param
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function actionAbout()
    {
         $param = $this->somefunction();
        return $this->render('about', [
             "param" => $param
        ]);
    }
}
```

As you can notice, I'm passing `param` to multiple views with the same content so I want some time-saving way to send it only one time to all views.

Is that possible?

Currently, I'm using the session to store values and call the session in required views. I want something more convenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Controller and View events to achieve that.

Add this to your controller:

```
use yii\web\View;

...

public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->view->on(View::EVENT_BEFORE_RENDER, function() {
        $this->view->params['param'] = ...;
    });

    return true;
}
```

If you want it in multiple controllers, either create another controller (extending from `yii\web\Controller`) for that and override `beforeAction` and then extend your controllers from custom one, or set it during application boostrap using `BoostrapInterface`.

Additionally you can add some condition:

```
if (in_array($action, ['create', 'update']) {
    ...
}
```

and custom param will be only passed in these actions.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller you can redefine the `init ()`  function thanks to which you can assign to a variable of the controller the value you're interested